# I am getting a 404 error for my GET request with express server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, http-status-code-404, get-request

I am writing a express endpoint to get me a user credentials from my mongoDB database using the email but i am getting back a 404 error when i test the endpoint with postman here is the code

```
/**GET: http://localhost:9000/api/user/success123@gmail.com */ //url endpoint
export async function getUser(req, res){
const { email } = req.params;

 try {
    if(!email) return res.status(501).send({ error: "Invalid Username"})

    UserModel.findOne({ email }, function(err, user){
        if(err) return res.status(500).send({ err });
        if(!user) return res.status(501).send({ error: "Couldn't Find User"});

        return res.status(200).send(user)
    })
    
 } catch (error) {
    return res.status(404).send({ error: "Cannot find user data"})
 }
}
```

Note:

1. the email address exist in my mongoDB atlas i have checked it.
2. I am using the GET method in postman

but my postman keeps showing me 404 error 'cannot find user data'

what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to consider encoding the "@" symbol in the email address using percent-encoding like this:

```
GET: http://localhost:9000/api/user/success123%40gmail.com
```

However, I'll suggest you pass the email as the body parameter instead of the params.

Answer (score 0):

`mongoose` is no longer support callback function in `findOne()`. You can hold the data in a variable or use `.then()`, `.catch()` block.

Here is the example of the solution of your code:

```
export async function getUser(req, res) {
  const { email } = req.params;
    
  try {
    if (!email)
      return res.status(501).json({ error: "Invalid Username" })
    
    await UserModel.findOne({ "email": email })
      .then((docs) => {
        return res.status(201).json(docs)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        return res.status(501).json(err)
      });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(404).send({ error: "Cannot find user data" })
  }
}
```

Here is some of things you have to consider,

1. Don't forget to use the `await` keyword in your async function.
2. Try to write the code in Ecmascript
3. Use key-value pair in `findOne()`. Use `{ "email": email }` instead of `{ email }`

I hope this helps!